Software's USB cannot be enumerated correctly on different computers
I implemented a USB XBOX device. It works fine on my computer, but not on my colleague's computer. Is this the reason?

The above is the final log that cannot be enumerated normally.

The above is part of the normal enumeration log. I can't find the reason for this.
